AutoSelectCertificateForUrls for Chrome not using default certificate
I'm using Selenium in Python to access various URLs. One uses "Certificate1" and all others use "Certificate2." Both certificates have the same Issuer but different Subject CNs. I am not using any group policies.  I have the registry setup like this:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\AutoSelectCertificateForUrls

1 = {"pattern": "https://www.example.com/secure/data-product-details?id=ABC-456", "filter": {"SUBJECT": {"CN": "Certificate1"}}}
2 = {"pattern": "[*.]", "filter": {"SUBJECT": {"CN": "Certificate2"}}}

When I try the first URL - https://www.example.com/secure/data-product-details?id=ABC-456
it selects Certificate1 correctly.
But when I try another URL - https://www.example.com/secure/data-product-details?id=DEF-789
it selects Certificate1 again, but should select Certificate2.
Is the problem that it doesn't distinguish between URL parameters?
I would eventually like to add more specific URLs, but need to get this "Default" working first.

certs are per domain, no?  "Is the problem that it doesn't distinguish between URL parameters?"  I would say so... anything after the domain is irrelevant to a cert.  However, I've never used this setting so just a guess.

@browsermator - It's not really the cert reading the URL parameters, it's Chrome reading the registry.  The registry tells Chrome which cert to use for that page.  But it doesn't seem to be working like that.  Perhaps once it uses a cert for a base URL, it's cached and cannot auto-select another cert for a different page.  But that seems to defeat the purpose...
